# Is the Navigator component the only way of switching screens in a react-native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am in the process of learning React-Native as I develop my first app, and have arrived at the point that I want to switch to a different screen when the user taps an item in my ListView.  In a couple of React-Native applications I saw, they included a Navigator component in their main index.*.js and used the Navigator to transition between screens. This looks like a good way to do things. 
However, for thoroughness, I would like to know if there are other ways in React-Native of switching between screens or if the Navigator component would be my only option.

Comment: I am leaving this question just in case more experienced users can provide insights.  However, I just realized that the Navigator is the controller in React-Native's MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NavigationExperimental](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html)

And have a look at [NavigationTransitioner](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/NavigationExperimental/NavigationTransitioner-AnimatedView-example.js) which is part of it